# make_parallel_group: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Tags: boost

I'm using make_parallel_group to perform concurrent reads on a websocket::streambeast::tcp_stream and a boost::asio::experimental::concurrent_channel, and It will exit as soon as It receive data from either one of them. However, I'm getting an error when trying to write data on the ws stream: "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."

This is the full code, https://pastebin.com/C6imR3m7

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/concurrent_channel.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/parallel_group.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/deferred.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>


namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using channel_t = boost::asio::experimental::concurrent_channel<void(boost::system::error_code, std::string data)>;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
net::awaitable<void>
do_session(
    net::io_context& ioc,
    channel_t& chan,
    std::string host,
    std::string port)
{
    // These objects perform our I/O
    auto resolver = net::use_awaitable.as_default_on(
        tcp::resolver(co_await net::this_coro::executor));
    auto ws = net::use_awaitable.as_default_on(
        websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>(co_await net::this_coro::executor));

    // Look up the domain name
    auto const results = co_await resolver.async_resolve(host, port);

    // Set a timeout on the operation
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
    auto ep = co_await beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).async_connect(results);

    // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
    // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
    // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
    host += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

    // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
    // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_never();

    // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
    ws.set_option(
        websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
            beast::role_type::client));

    // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
    ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](websocket::request_type& req)
    {
        req.set(http::field::user_agent,
        std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
        " websocket-client-coro");
    }));

    // Perform the websocket handshake
    co_await ws.async_handshake(host, "/");

    net::co_spawn(ioc, [&]()->net::awaitable<void> {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        co_await chan.async_send(ec, "hello,world!", boost::asio::use_awaitable);
    }, net::detached);

    try {
        while (true) {
            boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
            auto group = boost::asio::experimental::make_parallel_group(
                boost::asio::co_spawn(ioc, ws.async_read(buffer), boost::asio::deferred),
                boost::asio::co_spawn(ioc, chan.async_receive(boost::asio::use_awaitable), boost::asio::deferred));

            auto [order, ec1, bytes, ec2, data] = co_await group.async_wait(boost::asio::experimental::wait_for_one(), boost::asio::use_awaitable);
            if (order[0] == 0) {
                std::string str = beast::buffers_to_string(buffer.data());
                std::cout << "received data from websocket server: " << str << std::endl;
            }
            else if (order[0] == 1) {
                std::cout << "received data from chan: " << data << std::endl;
            }

            co_await ws.async_write(net::buffer(std::string("test"))); // HERE
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the WebSocket connection
    co_await ws.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal);

    // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // std::string host = "echo.websocket.org";
    // auto const port = "80";
    std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
    auto const port = "8080";

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;
    channel_t chan(ioc, 10);

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    net::co_spawn(ioc,
        do_session(std::ref(ioc), std::ref(chan), host, port),
        [](std::exception_ptr e)
    {
        if (e)
            try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(e);
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    });

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

see line 108 (`// HERE`).

Could you please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Runtime environment: Windows 11 + Boost 1.83

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think per-operation cancellation is not supported (yet? see https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/2325) on websockets. Basically, cancellation of the read invalidates future writes on the websocket.

You can probably alleviate the situation by using the `wait_for_one_success()`  condition instead of `wait_for_one()`.